# How do I stop warnings appearing when I increase the volume?

Tags: settings, volume-control

I am using Nexus 4 with Android 4.4.4 stock. Whenever I increase the volume while listening to music on my smartphone, I get a warning that listening at high volumes can cause problems to the ears. Is it possible to stop this message appearing?

I would prefer not to root the smartphone yet.

Comment: Well, you can't do that until or unless you root your device. Once you rooted your device you can move forward with the suggestion @sameer has guided.

Comment: Follow what @sameer said. There's a tutorial in LifeHacker website if you need. (Remember rooting is MUST).

Comment: See an alternative for non rooted device here https://android.stackexchange.com/q/188131/131553

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you are rooted, goto settings/sounds/volumes. Unchecked the safe headphone volume box and agree to warning about potential damage to your ears. That's what I did on my Nexus 7 w/4.4.4 ROM.

Answer (score 6):

If you are rooted, you can try one of the following

1.`NoSafeVolumeWarning` in [Xposed Framework](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/xposed-installer-versions-changelog-t2714053)

2 .`Media Tweak Settings` in  [Gravity Box](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/app-gravitybox-v3-1-5-tweak-box-android-t2554049)