# Is there any way to remove the sound alert message?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, volume-control, headphones

When I increase the volume with the headphones, a message appears saying that **prolonged listening with a loud sound can damage the ear**.
 
Is there any way to remove this message on my Smasung Galaxy Note 4 ?
Thank you

Comment: Isn't this the same as [How do I stop warnings appearing when I increase the volume?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/81664/16575)

Comment: Unfortunately no :/. I'm on android 6.0.1 and I just watch I do not have the volume option. Just "Sounds and Notifications".

Comment: @beeshyams It works ! I set Macrodroid on google play music app. I'm quiet now I can increase the volume on my headphones without having to remove the notification on my phone. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [confirmed by OP](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/188131/is-there-any-way-to-remove-the-sound-alert-message#comment242466_188131) the solution that worked is posted below

You can try [automation](/questions/tagged/automation).  I prefer [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid), being easy to learn and free (upto 5 macros)

Create a macro

**Trigger:** Notification → Notification received  → Select Application  → Google Play Music → Text content contains  → prolonged listening with a loud sound can damage the ear

**Actions:**

1. Clear Notifications  → Clear all
2. *Optional if you don't want notification sound* ; Volume Change  → Set notification on slider scale to zero

**Constraints​ :** Leave blank