# Disable notification sound for PingID on authentication

Tags: notifications, audio

PingID is an authentication tool used for 2FA login, after initial login to a system it will prompt the installed app on phone to loudly beep when it is asking for authentication (by swiping a widget). Since this is used in office, I don't want to annoy others around me and nor do I need a reminder sound when I know exactly when I will be asked to use the app.

Is there a way to disable the audible prompt only for PingID (or, if you don't know about this specific app, then steps to do so for any general app)? I'd prefer methods that use existing Settings or tools if possible, but am open to installing other apps if necessary.

Comment: You could silence the notification sound manually (and globally). App-specific solutions usually require root for that.

Comment: You can try the solution here by modifying it to include your app https://android.stackexchange.com/q/188131/131553